# Iteration returns the same result while crawling

Tags: scrapy, iteration

I'm new to Scrapy and i'm browsing through the manual book. I'm doing some exercises and stuck with these issue. While iterating through the list of books, the results always return the same ''key: value" pairs after iteration, despite tha fact, that there is 20 different elements in the page.

This is my code:

```py
import scrapy


class MyBooks(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bookstore'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for book in response.xpath('//article[@class="product_pod"]'):
            yield {

                'title': book.xpath('//h3/a/text()').get(),
                'price': book.xpath('//p[@class="price_color"]/text()').get(),

            }
```

And this is my result:

```
2020-02-07 12:03:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://books.toscrape.com>
    {'title': 'A Light in the ...', 'price': '£51.77'}
    2020-02-07 12:03:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://books.toscrape.com>
    {'title': 'A Light in the ...', 'price': '£51.77'}
    2020-02-07 12:03:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://books.toscrape.com>
    {'title': 'A Light in the ...', 'price': '£51.77'}
    2020-02-07 12:03:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://books.toscrape.com>
    {'title': 'A Light in the ...', 'price': '£51.77'}
    2020-02-07 12:03:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://books.toscrape.com>
    {'title': 'A Light in the ...', 'price': '£51.77'}
    2020-02-07 12:03:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://books.toscrape.com>
    {'title': 'A Light in the ...', 'price': '£51.77'}
    2020-02-07 12:03:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://books.toscrape.com>
```

Why is that? Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with `xpath` selectors, but for some reason it looks like `book.xpath('//h3/a/text()')` and `book.xpath('//p[@class="price_color"]/text()')` return a list of selectors with every book's data in them. To confirm this, you can call `.getall()` instead of `.get()` on these selectors, you will see that it returns a list of every book's result. I got it working with CSS selectors though:

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        for book in response.xpath('//article[@class="product_pod"]'):
            yield {
                'title': book.css('h3').css('a::text').get(),
                'price': book.css('.price_color::text').get()
            }
```

You can read more about selectors [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to use XPath selectors as much as possible, because i was told that XPath selectors are much more powerful than CSS. Nevertheless i succeed to resolve my problem. I just added a dot (.) before xpath queries - yield {

                'title': book.xpath('.//h3/a/text()').getall(),
                'price': book.xpath('.//p[@class="price_color"]/text()').getall(),
       

            }